# Download.File Issue with xls Excel Workbook

Tags: r, download, xls

I'm trying to download an Excel workbook `xls` using R's `download.file` function (`Windows 10, R version 3.4.4 (2018-03-15)`).

When I download the file manually (using Internet Explorer or Chrome) then the file downloads and I can then open it in Excel without any problems.

When I use `download.file` in R, the file downloads but size is smaller than correct download file - this file is `hmtl` file with some notes that my browser is not supported. Tyred different modes and no luck.

My code:

```
download.file(
        url = "https://www.atsenergo.ru/nreport?fid=696C3DB7A3F6019EE053AC103C8C8733",
        destfile = "C:/MyExcel.xls",
        mode = "wb",
        method = "auto"
      )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving this problem with RSelenium library. ATS site reject any query for downloading file (return `.hmtl` file with Required javascript enabled message) and in this case Selenium method only works. My code below (where `urlList` data frame with files download links):

```
rD <- rsDriver(port = 4444L,
               browser = "chrome",
               check = FALSE,
               geckover = NULL,
               iedrver = NULL,
               phantomver = NULL)
remDr <- rD$client
for (i in 1:nrow(urlList)) {
  tryCatch({
    row <- urlList[i,]

    remDr$navigate(row$url)

    webElem <-
      remDr$findElement(using =
                          'link text', row$FileName)
    webElem$clickElement()
  },
  error = function(e)
    logerror(paste(
      substr(e, 1, 50),
      atsCode,
      dateFileName,
      sep = "\t"
    ), logger = loggerName),
  finally = next)
}

remDr$close()
# stop the selenium server
rD[["server"]]$stop()
```